# In kotest is there a way to have a "before" hook run once for a TestContainer it's in?

Tags: kotlin, kotlintest, kotest

I'm trying to use Kotest to write nested tests that have hooks that only run once per nest level.  This is how mocha works in JavaScript and how RSpec works in ruby.  In mocha the function is called `before`. I tried using `beforeContainer` but it runs once for *each* nested container instead of just once for the entire container including any nested containers within that parent container. This is hard to explain, so below is a set of tests that I would expect to pass, if a `before` method existed in kotest that behaved like mocha's or RSpec's.  In short, each `before` method should only be called once, and only when tests in its container run (e.g., the `before` method inside `"nested level 2"` shouldn't run until the tests in `"nested level 1"` have run).

```kotlin
package foo.bar

import io.kotest.core.spec.style.DescribeSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class WidgetTest : DescribeSpec({
    var foo = "initial"
    var counterOne = 0
    var counterTwo = 0
    var counterThree = 0

    before {
        foo = "bar"
        counterOne++
    }

    it("foo should be bar") {
        foo shouldBe "bar"
        counterOne shouldBe 1
    }

    it("beforeSpec should have been called only once") {
        foo shouldBe "bar"
        counterOne shouldBe 1
    }

    it("counterTwo should be 0") {
        counterTwo shouldBe 0
    }

    it("counterThree should be 0") {
        counterThree shouldBe 0
    }

    describe("nested level 1") {
        before {
            foo = "buzz"
            counterTwo++
        }

        it("foo should be buzz") {
            foo shouldBe "buzz"
        }

        it("and counterOne should be 1") {
            counterOne shouldBe 1
        }

        it("and counterTwo should be 1") {
            counterTwo shouldBe 1
        }

        describe("nested level 2") {
            before {
                foo = "jazz"
                counterThree++
            }

            it("foo should be jazz") {
                foo shouldBe "jazz"
            }

            it("and counterOne should be 1") {
                counterOne shouldBe 1
            }

            it("and counterTwo should be 1") {
                counterTwo shouldBe 1
            }

            it("and counterThree should be 1") {
                counterThree shouldBe 1
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I can get close to what I want if I make the first `before` a `beforeSpec` and the other two `beforeContainer` (and move them above each nested container), but then `counterTwo` gets incremented twice: once for `"nested level 1"` and once for `"nested level 2"`.  I'm not sure if I'm just doing something wrong or if this capability simply doesn't exist in kotest.

Comment: Update: I added this as an issue in GitHub: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/2792